# Value of $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}{(4x^2-x)^{1/2} +2x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

The value of the $$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}{(4x^2-x)^{1/2} +2x}$$ is?

The answer given is $1/4$.

I rationalized and got $$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} \frac {-x}{|x|[(4- \frac {1}{x})^{1/2}-2]}$$ how to proceed further?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I misread it.

Comment: I don't see how your rationalization works. $-2|x|\neq -2x.$ In particular, when $x$ is negative $2x=-2|x|.$

Comment: You should get a rationalization: $$\frac{|x|}{|x|\left[\left(4-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}+2\right]}$$ when $x<0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, that's where I made the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is equivalent to
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(2|x|\left(1-\frac1{4x}\right)^{1/2}+2x\right)
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(-2x\left(1-\frac1{4x}\right)^{1/2}+2x\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}-2x\left(\left(1-\frac1{4x}\right)^{1/2}-1\right)\\
\end{align}$$
Then using the generalized binomial expansion we get that as $x\to0$
$$(1+x)^n=1+nx+o(x)$$
Hence our limit becomes
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to-\infty}-2x\left(\left(1-\frac1{4x}\right)^{1/2}-1\right)
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}-2x\left(1-\frac1{8x}+o\left(\frac1x\right)-1\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}-2x\left(-\frac1{8x}+o\left(\frac1x\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\frac14+o(1)\right)\\
&=\frac14\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

A more elementary solution :
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \big( \sqrt{4x^2-x} +2x \big) =\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{-x}{\sqrt{4x^2-x} -2x} =\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{4x^2+x}+2x} =\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{x}}+2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}+2}=\frac{1}{4}$$
where I used that
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty} f(-x)$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
(4x^2-x)^{1/2}+2x
&=\sqrt{4x^2-x}+2x
\\&=\frac{(\sqrt{4x^2-x}+2x)(\sqrt{4x^2-x}-2x)}{\sqrt{4x^2-x}-2x}
\\&=\frac{(4x^2-x)-4x^2}{\sqrt{4x^2-x}-2x}
\\&=\frac{4x^2-x-4x^2}{\sqrt{4x^2-x}-2x}
\\&=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{4x^2-x}-2x}
\\&=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{(2x)^2(1-\frac{1}{4x})}-2x}
\\&=\frac{-x}{2|x|\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4x}}-2x}
\\&\qquad [x<0]
\\&=\frac{-x}{-2x\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4x}}-2x}
\\&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4x}}+2}
\\&\to\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+0}+2}
\\&=\frac{1}{4}.
\end{align*}
(as $x\to-\infty$)

Answer (score 1):

Your rationalization is almost correct. It should be

$$\frac{-x}{\sqrt{4x^2-x}-2x} = \frac{-x}{|x|\left[\left(4-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}-\frac{2x}{|x|}\right]}.$$

You have assumed that $-2x = -2|x|,$ which is not true when $x$ is negative. But as $x\to-\infty,$ we can asume $x<0$ and thus $|x|=-x,$ so this is equal to

$$\frac{1}{\left(4-\frac1x\right)^{1/2}+2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Multiply by ${\sqrt{4x^2-x}-2x}\over {\sqrt{4x^2-x}-2x}$

The result is ${-x\over{\sqrt{4x^2-x}-2x}}$

$={{-x}\over {|x|\sqrt{4-{1\over x}}+2}}=$

${{-x}\over {-x\sqrt{4-{1\over x}}+2}}$

${1\over {\sqrt{4-{1\over x}}+2}}$.

Comment: $-2x$ is not under the root.

Comment: $-2x=2|x|,$ at least when $x<0.$

Comment: This answer is still wrong. Instead of $-\frac 2x$ in the denominator, it should be simple $+2.$

Answer (score 0):

$y:=-x$, and $ \lim y \rightarrow +\infty$.

$(4y^2+y)^{1/2}-2y=$

$((2y+1/4)^2-1/16)^{1/2}-2y$;

$z:=2y+1/4$;

We get

$((z^2-1/16)^{1/2}-z) +1/4$;

Since

$\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} (z^2-1/16)^{1/2}-z)=0$ (why?), and we are done.

Note:

$(z^2-1/16)^{1/2}-(z^2)^{1/2}= $

$\dfrac{-1/16}{(z^2-1/16)^{1/2}+(z^2)^{1/2}}$

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of comfort, we change the sign and evaluate

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}{(4x^2+x)^{1/2}-2x}$$

which is

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{{(4x^2+x)^{1/2}+2x}}$$

or

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{{(4+\frac1x)^{1/2}+2}}=\frac14.$$